# Post build commit to svn fails on jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, certificate

In Jenkins, I can checkout from the SVN server with the UI for credentials from subversion plugin. However, trying to commit new generated files after build through the batch command line with this command:

svn commit -m "log of revision"

I get the following error:

> svn: E170013: Commit failed (details follow): svn: E170013: Unable to
>   connect to a repository at URL 'https://blah/svn/blah/blah' svn:
>   E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate
>   issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted

I get the same error when adding --username blah --password ****** options to the command.

Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like this link leads to a malicious mirror of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should install a valid and trusted server certificate onto your Subversion server.
2. In case you can't install the certificate, add [`--trust-server-cert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.trust_server_cert) option to the command line Jenkins runs.